# Using Plex with Chromecast vs RasPlex?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromecast, plex

For the last few months I've been using `Plex` with `Chromecast` to stream video to my TV. The `Plex Server` runs on my laptop. The data is streamed over wifi through the laptop from a shared network drive (not NAS). I use the Plex iOS app on an iPad as a remote control. Probably not the best setup but it's been working pretty well.

I just heard about [RasPlex](http://www.rasplex.com/index.html#) *"A Plex Client for the Raspberry Pi computer"* and am trying to understand what it does that is different than my current set up.

In the iOS iPad app, I select Chromecast (connected to TV) to "cast" to – so is the iOS app the Plex Client? Would there be any advantage to switching to RasPlex?

Ideally what I would like to do is get the Plex Server onto a Raspbery Pi and free up my laptop – but apparently the Pi doesn't do transcoding.

A bit confused. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the rasplex is a dedicated client, that automatically uses CEC over HDMI to select movies etc from. so basically a mini computer that turns itself automatically in a client without having to use other remote tools. so basically you turn your tv into a smart tv, as long as the rasplex is connected with wifi/network cable and hdmi